# Angular Checkboxes do not work

Tags: angular, checkbox

I try to get checkboxes to work, but I can't figure out the proper way to do it. Here is what I have:

```html
  <div class="form-group">
    <div class="checkbox col-md-3">
      <label translate>
        <input type="checkbox" name="notification-info" [checked]="selectedInfoSubscription" (change)="infoChange($event)">
        lbl_notificationtype_information
      </label>
    </div>
  </div>
```

As soon as `selectedInfoSubscription` (boolean) changes it's state internally, it won't get propagated to the checkbox. What am I doing wrong?

I tried `ngModel`, `ngChecked`, `ngOnValueChange` and so on, but nothing worked. When I load an entity, the checkboxes stay unchecked although the booleans itself changed their state.

**EDIT:** TS code:

```ts
public selectedInfoSubscription: boolean;
//...
ngOnInit() {
  this.selectedInfoSubscription = true;
}
```

Comment: post your ts code also

Comment: @Sajeetharan Done

Comment: Looks like you're using wrong variables. In the template, you're referring to selectedInfoSubscription while in the class you using selectedErrorSubscription. Is that a typo?

Comment: @sickelap Actually I just copied the wrong code. Need to correct it. But that's sadly not the problem. The code is highly simplified, because I know the code and the variables itself shouldn't be the problem. I used the console to validate that the variables itself change, while the checkboxes won't chance their state.

Comment: Seems to be working fine in plunker. Check for yourself: https://plnkr.co/edit/UKW2KK5tcNK6BMjY2hJq?p=preview

Comment: Aha! I wonder what infoChange method does?

Comment: @sickelap You were right. The above works, the problem was in a loop, like you probably guessed. Something like 2 methods that listened to a change. Thank you all. :)